# Azure Same domain used for multiple Azure websites

Tags: c#, wpf, azure, dns, azure-web-app-service

Our DNS/webserver was setup so www.mysite.com went to the website, and mysite.com went to the service setup via DNS. This service is used by a wpf application with multiple clients all with different versions. So just changing the service url in the wpf application is not going to work as clients just don't upgrade and some are running on older versions and won't upgrade.

Is there anyway to replicate this in Azure? Since you need to verify the domain by creating a cname, I can't have the same cname point to different addresses. So any ideas on how to do this with Azure?

Would like to keep the service separate from the website.

EDIT: We have hundreds of subdomains, one for each client. So client1.example.com, client2.example.com, www.example.com, etc. And the service example.com. The service url is coded into the legacy wpf application so can't change. The wcf service is currently a app service was well.

Comment: Just to be clear, you're not looking for something like Azure Traffic Manager, are you?  If not, Michael B's answer should give you what you want

Answer (score 1):

www.example.com and example.com are distinct and separate domains. It is perfectly feasible to have example.com point to one Azure site and www.example.com to point to another.

Comment: How do I get around the CNAME requirement? I can't add 2 seperate CNAME records of awverify to DNS. I forgot to mention that this is a wildcard domain with many different subdomains.